# Another text based adventure game; while loop battle system

Tags: c, while-loop

Thank you to anyone who tries to help me with this!

So what should happen here is that if you run this, and you pick class choice 1,2 or 3, then when you go into the battle your attacks are different etc.

I'm making it so that you have to win rock paper scissors to be able to attack, so if the computer wins it attacks you.

For class choice 1, this works, however for the other two is doesn't and I'm lost as to why.

I'm very new to c so sorry if I'm missing something obvious!

For example if you pick class choice 3, guardian, and you win or lose the rock paper scissors game, nothing happens at all, where as it should let you attack or him attack

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int i;
int playerschoice, compchoice;

main()
{
    int i;
    int choice1,choice2;
    int class_choice,warrior,rogue,guardian;
    int HoodMan_Health = 30;
    int HoodMan_HealthCurrent;
    int HoodManAtk = 25;
    int HoodManDef = 15;
    int RogueAtk = 100;
    int RogueDef = 10;
    int WarriorAtk = 50;
    int WarriorDef = 50;
    int GuardianAtk = 10;
    int GuardianDef = 100;
    int health = 100;
    int currenthealth;
    int difficulty;
    int level;

    printf("\n1.Rogue [100atck 10def]\n\n2.Warrior [50atck 50def]\n\n3.Guardian    [10atck         100def]\n");
    printf("\nYour choice?\t");
    scanf("%i",&class_choice);

    if (class_choice == 1 || class_choice == 2 ||class_choice == 3) 
    {
        printf("\nLets play...\n\n");
        system ("PAUSE");
    } 
    else 
    {
        printf("\nThat was not a choice\n");
        return(0);
    }

    while ( (currenthealth>0)&&(HoodMan_Health>0) ) // while both healths are above zero do this battle
        rockpaperscissors();
    {
        if (((playerschoice == 1)&&(compchoice == 3)) || ((playerschoice == 2)&&(compchoice == 1)) || ((playerschoice == 3)&&(compchoice == 1)))
        {
            printf("You attack the hooded man\n");
            if (class_choice == 1)
            {
                HoodMan_Health=HoodMan_Health-(RogueAtk*0.5+HoodManDef*0.25);
                printf("The Hooded Man's health is now %i\n\n",HoodMan_Health);
            }
            else if (class_choice == 2)
            {
                HoodMan_Health=HoodMan_Health-(WarriorAtk*0.5+HoodManDef*0.25);
                printf("The Hooded Man's health is now %i\n\n",HoodMan_Health);
            }
            else if (class_choice == 3)
            {
                HoodMan_Health=HoodMan_Health-(GuardianAtk*0.5+HoodManDef*0.25);
                printf("The Hooded Man's health is now %i\n\n",HoodMan_Health);
            }
        }
        else if (((playerschoice == 3)&&(compchoice == 1)) || ((playerschoice == 1)&&(compchoice == 2)) || ((playerschoice == 1)&&(compchoice == 3)))
        {
            printf("The Hooded Man attacks you\n");
            if (class_choice == 1)
            {
                currenthealth=currenthealth-(HoodManAtk+RogueDef*0.5);
                printf("Your health is now %i\n\n\n",currenthealth);
            }
            else if (class_choice == 2)
            {
                currenthealth=currenthealth-(HoodManAtk+WarriorDef*0.5);
                printf("Your health is now %i\n\n\n",currenthealth);
            }
            else if (class_choice == 3)
            {
                currenthealth=currenthealth-(HoodManAtk+GuardianDef*0.5);
                printf("Your health is now %i\n\n\n",currenthealth);
            }
        }
    }

    if (currenthealth<0)
    {
        printf("You died\n");
        return (0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You killed the hooded man\n");
    }
}

void rockpaperscissors()
{
    printf("Enter 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper and 3 for Scissors\n");
    scanf("%i",&playerschoice);

    if ( playerschoice == 1 )
    {
        printf("You are going with: Rock...\n");
    }
    else if ( playerschoice == 2 )
    {
        printf("You are going with: Paper...\n");
    }
    else if ( playerschoice == 3 )
    {
        printf("You are going with: Scissors...\n");
    }
    else if ( playerschoice != 1||2||3)
    {
        printf("that was not a choice");
        return(0);
    }

    // initialize random seed: //
    srand (time(NULL));
    // set compchoice to random number from 1 to 3 //
    compchoice=rand() %3+1;

    if (compchoice == 1)
    {
        printf("\nThe computer is going with: Rock...\n\n");
    }
    else if (compchoice == 2)
    {
        printf("\nThe computer is going with: Paper...\n\n");
    }
    else if (compchoice == 3)
    {
        printf("\nThe computer is going with: Scissors...\n\n");
    }

    {
        if (((playerschoice == 1)&&(compchoice == 3)) || ((playerschoice == 2)&&(compchoice == 1)) || ((playerschoice == 3)&&(compchoice == 1)))
        {
            printf("you win\n");
        }
        else if (((playerschoice == 3)&&(compchoice == 1)) || ((playerschoice == 1)&&(compchoice == 2)) || ((playerschoice == 1)&&(compchoice == 3)))
        {
            printf("you lose\n");
        }
        else if (((playerschoice == 1)&&(compchoice == 1)) || ((playerschoice == 2)&&(compchoice == 2)) || ((playerschoice == 3)&&(compchoice == 3)))
        {
            printf("it's a draw\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, 'else if ( playerschoice != 1||2||3)' will always evaluate to true.

Comment: Note that 1. the body of your `while`-loop consists entirely of only `rockpaperscissors();` and after that you have a compound-statement (that just gets executed once). And 2. you have useless compound-statement at the end of `rockpaperscissors` that you might have meant to make the body of an `if`/`else`-statement. Hint: proper formatting & indentation really help catch these things early on.

Comment: Also note, you are mixing integer and floating point math. This will result in truncation. Eg, 'HoodManDef*.25' = 3.75 (when HoodManDef= 15) but when converted back to an int the result will be 3.

Comment: There's no question in this question, just a bunch of facts and then a big hunk of code. **What's your question?**

Answer (score 1):

Here are the chief errors in your program:

To use: `system("pause");` you should `include <windows.h>`

To use: `time(NULL)` you should `include <time.h>`

`string.h` isn't really required in your program.

You haven't initialized `currenthealth` which can lead to unpredictable outcome.

You have made variables like  `health` and `HoodMan_HealthCurrent` but are not using them.

Call to `rockpaperscissors()` should be inside the while block.
Putting it outside makes the loop infinite and the code in the block never gets executed!

If you want to use floating point arithmetic like `HoodManDef*0.25` you should declare it as float  or else it will be rounded off.

The condition `else if ( playerschoice != 1||2||3)` is wrong(always true) and redundant(The above three conditions imply that playerschoice will not be 1,2 or 3 ).
A simple `else` will suffice.

`rockpaperscissors()` is a void function.You cannot `return(0);`. Use a simple `return;` instead.

You don't have to use `srand()` every time you call the function.You can simply use it at the start of program or when each game starts(if you plan to make it re playable without restarting) .

Some Problems with the game:

You are adding character's defense to opponent's attack! i.e the more defense i have , the more powerful my opponent will become . You should subtract instead.

Defense of warrior and Guardian is so much that their health won't decrease even if attacked by the hoodman.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering you helped alot! I have two questions, firstly how so I initialize currenthealth? I'm very new to c. And secondly, the part where if the player wins they attack and if the computer wins it attacks? Well, when I change that 'else if' to an 'else', it works but it will work for both a computer win and a draw, is there anyway I can make it just for a computer win?

Comment: int currenthealth = 45; //initialisation

Comment: @user3263564 I don't see any reason why replacing                   else if(playerschoice != 1||2||3)
{
    printf("that was not a choice");  
    return(0);  
}
with
else
{
    printf("that was not a choice");
    return;
}
will have any effect on computer winning or draws.

Comment: @meryln thanks again! No sorry, maybe I wasnt being clear. Within the while loop. Basically it runs rock paper scissors, if I win I attack, if the computer wins, the computer should attack but it doesn't work and I wondered if it was something to do with my "else if" in my while loop?